# Show $a e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ has exactly one real root

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Show that the equation $a e^x=1+x+x^2$, where $a$ is a positive constant, has exactly one real root.

Looking at the graphs of both $ae^x$ and $1+x+x^2$, they will intersect on the left half of the plane when $a>1$ and on the right half when $a<1$ (because a makes $e^x$ grow faster or slower). So if I could find a point $x_1$ where $a e^{x_1}-(1+x_1+{x_1}^{2})<0$ and a point $x_2$ where $a e^{x_2}-(1+x_2+{x_2}^2)>0$, by the intermediate value theorem, the equation would have a real root. Also,since the derivative of $a e^x-(1+x+x^2)$ is always positive, I could colclude that there can't exist another real root.

So my question is, how can I find $x_1$ and $x_2$? I can't figure out how to express $x$ in terms of $a$.

EDIT: I'm really sorry, I wrote the equation wrong everywhere. I should read $ae^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ instead of $ae^x=1+x+x^2$. Changed to reflect that.

EDIT2: The question appears as it was originaly written. I'll make new question with the right equation. Sorry if I bothered anyone.

Comment: But do we really know the derivative of $ae^x -(1+x+x^2)$ is always positive?  I get a derivative of this to be $ae^x - (1+2x)$, and it isn't obvious to me that even assuming $a \gt 1$ suffices to make the derivative positive everywhere.  But if you knew that, and could find points above and below the x-axis, yes it would prove there's exactly one real root.

Comment: You really shouldn't change your question when you already have received answers to the original one. (It's a bit disrespectful of the work that was put into answering the originial question...) It's better to post a new question.

Comment: Sorry, It was a silly mistake from my part not to check that I wrote the correct data, I'll post a new one. I swear I didn't mean to be disrespectful.

Comment: @mrf I disagree.  It's a bad idea to change the fundamental nature of a question instead of asking a second, but fixing a typo in a constant, within an hour of posting the question, is much better than throwing a second virtually-duplicate question into the mix.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: That "little typo" completely changes the question.

Comment: @mrf It completely changes the _answer_, but it changes none of the methods used to solve it.

Comment: So should I post another another question? The title already changed

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning and decide for yourself. My answer will have to be deleted if you stick with the new question, since it doesn't apply to the updated version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Let $f(x) = ae^x - 1 - x- x^2$. If $a = 1$, then $f(0) = 0$, but it's easy to check that $f(x)$ is negative for small positive values of $x$ and positive for large values of $x$, so $f$ has one more zero.

(Numerically, the second zero is located at $x \approx 1.793282133$.)

**Added:** In fact, with more work you can show that the equation has three roots for $1 < a < 3e^{-1} \approx 1.103638324$ (and two roots, one of which is double for $a=1$ and $a=3e^{-1}$).

Comment: I believe some values of $a$ give three solutions. e.g., $a=1.01$ (from examining a plot).

Comment: @DavidMitra You're right of course, I typed that too quickly, the double root at $x=0$ when $a=1$ splits into two single roots for $a > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

To show the existence of $x_1$, I would take a look at the behaviour of the $ae^x-1-x-x^2$, when x goes to $-\infty$. The limes should be $-\infty$? - Maybe use L'Hopital.

Therefore the function should be negative anywhere. The same procedure should lead you to a point $x_2$, where the function is positive.

Comment: Did you mean limes or limit?